# UIImagePickerController - crops picture to square (in portrait)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using the UIImagePickerController to take and edit a picture. it works fine in landscape, but in portrait it will crop the picture into a square (does not allow to reduce the image to fit fully into the square crop field like in landscape. Any ideas?

code:

```
-(IBAction)initCamera:(id)sender{

//Init imagePicker instance
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
[imagePicker setDelegate:self];

[imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
[imagePicker setShowsCameraControls:YES];
[imagePicker setAllowsEditing:YES];

[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
[imagePicker release];
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Check out [GKImagePicker](https://github.com/gekitz/GKImagePicker) library, it allows to set your custom image crop area, like this:

```
self.imagePicker = [[GKImagePicker alloc] init];
self.imagePicker.cropSize = CGSizeMake(320, 90);
self.imagePicker.delegate = self;

[self presentModalViewController:self.imagePicker.imagePickerController animated:YES];
```

Comment: it doesn't allow to set camera as sourcetype. It works with  gallery only!

Comment: @George it allows to use images from both gallery and camera.

Comment: I updated the answer to include a sample line for setting sourceType

Comment: @JoshLehman I am having same problem and this looks perfect but I can not see how you can set the source.

Comment: @RecycledSteel You should use self.imagePicker.imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

Comment: When i add GK Library and images ,  it gives me errors . What to do .?

Answer (score 12):

I know its really late to answer this question, But someone may find this helpful.

Change

```
[imagePicker setAllowsEditing:YES];
```

To

```
[imagePicker setAllowsEditing:NO];
```

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: This simply disables cropping. Imagine a use-case where someone wanted to upload a full-size portrait, yet wanted to crop out parts of a landscape photo.

Comment: @carbocation yes that can be a case. But thats whole new functionality i guess, that you can manage by checking **imageOrientation** property of image in `didFinishPickingImage:` delegate method of `UIImagePickerController`

Answer (score 4):

You can provide a custom cropping UI, but there is no way to change just the cropping rectangle of the standard one.

[This](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010400) link might help with that.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just wondering why cropping works ok for landscape (I can fit the whole image into the cropping square, so nothing gets lost), but not for portrait, where it doesn't allow to fit the image into the square.