# UIIMagePickerController + Camera + full screen capture photo

Tags: ios, iphone

Hi I am using `UIImagePickerController` with source type camera. I am wondered it not showing full capture mode like iOS contact app (taking profile pic from camera).

My code shows the top and bottom bar with black screen and iOS native show full screen capturing same for next retake screen.

Here is my screen shots[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

imagePickerController.delegate = self;
imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage, nil];
imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePickerController.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;

UIView *controllerView = imagePickerController.view;

controllerView.alpha = 0.0;
controllerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);

[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:controllerView];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
              delay:0.0
            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
         animations:^{
             controllerView.alpha = 1.0;
         }
         completion:nil];
```

Comment: Not working but shrink the camera I want Exact the Iphone native Contact app open the capture image while editing profile photo with camera

Comment: @sanjay, the thing you do here is – most possibly – very, but very wrong idea. You're tearing a view off from its view controller which handles all its functionality, which is never a good option when talking about private, Apple-provided classes like this one. In best case, this would lead to void / non-working code with leaks, in worse case, instant crash.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a default behaviour of `UIImagePickerController` (with black bars around capture area, at least on some devices).

Contacts app probably just alters its `-cameraViewTransform` property before presentation to fill the whole screen with the capture view, but this setting differs according to device and capture quality you're about to use.

Comment: As I said, you may try updating ```-cameraViewTransform``` property of ```UIImagePickerController``` before showing it to user, BUT it's position is inconsistent between Capture and Retake screens IIRC, so you would have to make A) some deeper magic by mangling / swizzling capturing functionality etc. or B) use completely different 3rd-party component. ```UIImagePickerController``` is basically not very customizable.

Comment: You are right . After setting CGFloat cameraTransformX = 1; CGFloat cameraTransformY = 1.5;
    Camerapicker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(Camerapicker.cameraViewTransform, cameraTransformX, cameraTransformY); Picker shows full screen but Retake screen still remaining as default picker shows

Comment: Yeah, but remember: • the proper / exact pixel-perfect value of transformation differs per device and orientation • you should transform both axes with the same value, otherwise the capture view will be distorted

Comment: I dont know much about transformation is above value is good or please tell me what should be best for different devices

Comment: Well, 1.5 should do the trick :) but apply that on both X and Y sides. You can experiment with lesser value until the black margin appears. The most optimal value would be a calculation between capture view frame and screen frame to use the MAX of screen.width/capture.width and screen.height/capture.height, but that is still vague and you don't even have (public) access to camera view directly to get its frame. For basic use, any Bulgarian constant is fine then. :)

Comment: Ok 1.5 works good but what to do with Retake screen it still showing same not full screen .?